# Немного запутался в сортировке слияния списков. Под "списком" здесь считают "записи" - R?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

Немного запутался в сортировке слияния списков. Под "списком" здесь считают "записи" - R?
В алгоритме(книга Кнут 3 том) - пункт L1: сказано подготовить два списка, но эти списки из R никак потом не участвуют в алгоритме, зачем они?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `R` -- это элемент списка, одна запись (*"record"*, *"struct"*) , которая состоит из линка `L` (указывающего на другую запись), ключа `K` и м.б. других полей. По описанию очень похоже, что записи расположены в массиве (тогда `L` это индекс массива с записью, на которую ссылается данная запись)

Comment: @avp спасибо. Мне про списки не совсем ясно, все равно же рассматривается один список(массив) в алгоритме

Comment: Я не вникал в алгоритм. Написано, что в начале там один список. Затем в тексте упоминаются два сливаемых списка, наверное где-то в тексте есть описание, как исходный список делится на 2 (или несколько), которые потом сливаются в один уже упорядоченный